# Ошибка в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
root.geometry('300x250')
root.title('Test')
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.9)
root['bg'] = '#ccc'
root.iconbitmap('D:/programming/Python/shorter.ico')

def conn():
    UT = user_text.get()

    field.insert(0.0, f'{UT}\n')

_test = Label(
    text = '',
    font = 'Comfortaa 20',
    fg = '#3d3d42',
    bg = '#878787',
    )

_text = Label(
    text = '',
    font = 'Comfortaa 16',
    fg = '#3d3d42',
    bg = '#ccc',
    )

_input = Entry(root,
    font = 'Consolas 15',
    fg = '#eff5c9',
    bg = '#48494f',
    relief = 'solid',
    justify = 'center',
    )

enter = Button(
    text = 'ввод',
    font = 'Consolas 12',
    fg = '#eff5c9',
    bg = '#48494f',
    relief = 'solid',
    command = conn,
    )

global field
field = Text(root,
    width = 25,
    height = 10,
    command = conn,
    )

_test.pack()
_text.pack()
_input.pack()
enter.pack(pady = 3)
field.pack(pady = 3)

enter.bind('<Button-1>', conn)

root.mainloop()
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы текст, который я ввожу, при нажатии на кпопку, выводился в поле ниже, но при запуске кода мне выдает такую ошибку:

```
  File "D:\programming\Python\shorter.py", line 69, in <module>
    field = Text(root,
  File "C:\Users\dimas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3559, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'text', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\dimas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-command"
```

Comment: что такое `user_text` в функции?
UPD: В вашей программе только одно поле для ввода текста. И это то поле, в которое вы почему-то хотите вставлять текст, который набираете. Или чего-то не хватает, или можно просто писать в это поле и все сразу будет там. Если же вы хотите находу форматировать вводимый текст, тогда надо брать его не из `user_text`, а из `field`

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то из текста ошибки можно сделать вывод, что в строке `field = Text(root,...` (т.е. вот в этом месте):

```
field = Text(root,
    width = 25,
    height = 10,
    command = conn,
    )
```

у виджета Text нет такого параметра как `command`, который вы ему зачем-то передаёте.